# Quotient Sets and Isomorphism Theorem

Tags: category-theory, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

Suppose we have a set $S$ equipped with an equivalence relation $\sim$. The set of $\sim$ equivalence classes of $S$ is sometimes called 'the quotient set of $S$ by $\sim$'. This reminds me of other notions of quotient like a quotient group or a quotient vector space.

Can these be brought under the same umbrella in category theory as the name suggests? In particular, are there isomorphism theorems for equivalence relations just as there are for groups and vector spaces? Are any of these theorems the fundamental theorem of equivalence relations?

Comment: Well, first I hope you know that quotient groups/rings/vector spaces are all examples of a quotient set under some equivalence relation. Next, given a map between two sets $f:X\to Y$, there’s a natural equivalence relation: $a\sim b\iff f(a)=f(b)$. Then, every surjective map $f:X\to Y$ gives a bijection $\tilde{f}:X/\sim\to Y$. So, you can think of this as the first isomorphism theorem for sets. Is there something else/deeper you had in mind?

Comment: Since you tagged this with `category-theory`, each of the examples you have listed is an instance of a coequalizer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coequalizer